# NFC tag security - Android

Tags: android, security, nfc

I'm working on application to work with nfc tags. Is there any way to secure a tag that only my application can write on it? Is there any good tutorial on this? I cant find anything about that.

Comment: Check out the DesFire EV1 tag - for example (as there may be better alternatives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your tag to be read-only by setting it's locking bits, but in that way you won't be able to rewrite your tag ever. A possible solution to your issue is to store your tag's content somewhere(in database or in the cloud). After that you will be able to change your tag's content just by reading it's ID.
Here's a good tutorial on how to read and write NFC tags:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html
And here's a method that locks NFC tag:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#makeReadOnly%28%29